# Memory is leaked only in some machines

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

We've got a situation where our application is leaking memory while doing some periodic action.

The test scenario is composed of a series of processes across two relatively complex WPF windows.

The weird thing about the situation is that memory only gets leaked on SOME machines, while others, having exactly the same hardware, can be working for really long times (repeating the process every minute) having their memory almost unchanged (once the GC gets rid of used memory, etc).

This is .NET + WPF. Any ideas about where to start looking? What can cause leaks in only some machines? (we're talking about a 30 machine test scenario).

I have few experience with WPF, could the graphic card had anything to do with it?

Comment: Regardless of same hardware. Does every machine have the exact same DLL/Libraries installed.  And can you track down to which assembly / etc.. is actually leaking?

Comment: Are those machines running the same version of the OS and .NET?

Comment: Machines are cloned using the same base software and basic libraries, including users and configuration. Only thing that might really differ between them is different drivers as sometimes testers install updated drivers and don't really have a control over which driver is installed. But basically same hardware and software.

Comment: Can you elaborate of what this periodic action is?

Comment: Can you also elaborate on how much memory you're leaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we've found the answer... We're still testing but it seems the application is not leaking memory anymore.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967634

> A memory leak occurs in the render
> thread of a WPF application when you
> perform one of the following actions:
>
> You use the software-rendering
> pipeline to render a 3D scene that
> includes a VisualBrush object or a
> DrawingBrush object. For example, you
> are using the software-rendering
> pipeline when you perform one of the
> following actions: You render the
> scene by using the RenderTargetBitmap
> class.
>
> You print the scene. You set
> the rendering tier property to 0. You
> render the scene over a remote desktop
> connection.
>
> You render a scene by
> using the WriteableBitmap class on a
> computer that does not use the Windows
> Display Driver Model (WDDM). You use
> the hardware-rendering pipeline to
> render a scene by using a tiled
> VisualBrush object or a tiled
> DrawingBrush object on a computer that
> does not use the WDDM.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something simple you may try. Download [SysInternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), run your application and then go to the Performance tab in the properties of the process. There you will see real-time statistics about the different handles: GDI Handles, User Handles, ... Now observe over time whether those handles grow.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with a profiler to see where the hot spots are and what kind of memory usage patterns you see in this periodic action. It's tough to say what can cause such an issue, but remember that GC is not deterministic so one could get into such strange scenarios.

Edit: Agreed with OP's comment on my post there. I guess what I was tyrying to get at is that even with the same hardware and software there is still a level of indeterminism inherent to the system.

Comment: But i wouldn't expect to get OutOfMemory exceptions in one tests and not in others. I would expect that to remain deterministic as the GC would "jump in" to provide available memory when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I use Ant Profiler to check my application for memory leaks, there are many other applications out there for testing this but you should consider using one and make sure there isnt something that is leaking and its coincidental that a few machines are showing the results.